# Copying Multiple Rows in Excel to a Single Row without Losing Data

Tags: merge

I have hundreds of rows of raw data in a CSV.  It is stacked like this:

ID.....SS.....P.....Window

S1235...345...48.....Fall

S1235...460....68....Winter

S1123....389....50....Fall

S1123.....598....98.....Winter

What I would like to do is match it up so that all of the IDs match with similar ID on one row only (without doing a manual copy and paste) so it looks like this:

ID.....SS.....P.....Window

S1235...345...48.....Fall..... S1235...460....68....Winter

S1123....389....50....Fall.....S1123.....598....98.....Winter

I don't care if there are multiple columns...because I will manually delete what I don't need.  What I need is for all the data with the same ID to appear on one row only.  Each piece of information needs to be in it's own cell.

I appreciate the help in advance...I'm not very good with this stuff...but it would be a HUGE time saver if you can help me out!